# Customized wordpress theme locally put on someones WordPress account

Tags: themes, installation, local-installation

I have an inssue with Wordpress themes installation. On my local computer I have run the WordPress themes which is stored in htdocs file. Now my client want me to upload this local files to his WordPress website. But I have tried to upload it and it gives me an error.I do not want to start from scratch again. So is there a way to get my local customized WordPress themes (which has a total different lay-out and text) installed on my clients original WordPress account.

The unzipped file structure on my local computer

-wordpress

-wp-admin
-wp-content
-wp-includes

Anyone an idea here?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have developed custom theme, just zip your theme folder.
Now login to your client WordPress site,From dashboard menu select Appearance->themes -> click to add new-> click upload theme. now upload your zip theme folder and active the theme.

Comment: Which file do I have to zip? The parent file called wordpress (which contains three different themes) could not be uploaded, it gives me an error when I do that.

Comment: Your theme folder only.

Comment: PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature

Comment: visit the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771578/wordpress-theme-upload-error-pclzip-err-bad-format

Comment: is it ok now @f?

Comment: Not really, I downloaded the wordpress themes and unzipped that couple weeks ago. Then dragged that files into the folder (htdocs), did not seperate the themes and dragged all three different themes into one folder inside htdocs-> wordpress-> wp-content -> themes.

Comment: which theme you have developed then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47586/discussion-between-frontend-employee-and-kanon-chowdhury).

Comment: Found the answer. I was extracting the file to Winrar, must be Winzip. My bad